# msbuild unable to find files in my Assets folder

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, msbuild

I am trying to build my first uwp application. I am new to c# as well. I am using visual studio build tools 2019. I think I have done everything right but when I run msbuild, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Projects\C\UapHello\uaphello.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
```

(_ValidateAppxPackage target) ->
  Package.appxmanifest(41,9): error APPX0703: Manifest references file 'Assets\Square150x150Logo.png' which is not part
 of the payload. [C:\Projects\C\UapHello\uaphello.csproj]
  Package.appxmanifest(42,9): error APPX0703: Manifest references file 'Assets\Square44x44Logo.png' which is not part o
f the payload. [C:\Projects\C\UapHello\uaphello.csproj]
  Package.appxmanifest(27,6): error APPX0703: Manifest references file 'StoreLogo.png' which is not part of the payload
. [C:\Projects\C\UapHello\uaphello.csproj]
  Package.appxmanifest(45,27): error APPX0703: Manifest references file 'Assets\SplashScreen.png' which is not part of
the payload. [C:\Projects\C\UapHello\uaphello.csproj]

I am pretty sure these files exist in said folder.
I am including my csproj and appmanifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5" 
  xmlns:desktop4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/4" 
  xmlns:iot2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10/2" 
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 iot2 desktop4">

  <Identity
    Name="IggyMakesThings"
    Publisher="CN=IggyMakesThings, O=IggyMakesThings, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />


  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="11a54d62-0d60-4e17-820d-1fa537715b3a" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

    <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17763.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>uaphello</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>IggyMakesThings</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>


  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="uaphello.exe"
      EntryPoint="UAPHello.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="UAPSample"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="UAP C# Sample"
        BackgroundColor="#000000">
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
        <uap:DefaultTile>
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>


</Package>
```

And csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Win32</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>uaphello</RootNamespace>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>true</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>  
  </PropertyGroup>


  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Win32'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|Win32'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" Version="6.2.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
     <SubType>Designer</SubType>
   </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>

   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />

</Project>
```

Please help

Comment: How about the build result when you build your UWP project with Visual Studio on your local? And have you install the UWP workload when you install the VS build tools? Please also share your MSBuild command line to us so that we could reproduce this on my side.

Comment: I just use the command msbuild. Also I only use visual studio build tools 2019. Do not have the complete visual studio

Comment: That's what I am saying. I just type in "msbuild" at the command prompt and it does the rest. I already have the csproj file so I believe it takes it from there.

Comment: That's what I am saying. I just type in "msbuild" at the command prompt and it does the rest. I already have the csproj file so I believe it takes it from there.

Comment: @daibatzu Hi, any update for this issue? Please let me know if it's helpful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think something missing in your .csproj file caused this issue.

**Steps to reproduce same issue:**

1.Create a new Blank App(Universal Windows)

2.In VS, for those .png resources:Exclude from the project

3.Copy the solution to build server where only has build tools

4.Restore the nuget packages and build the project with command like:

```
msbuild path/xxx.csproj(or xxx.sln) /p:Platform=X64 /p:AppxBundle=Always
```

5.Get the error below:
[image]

You can follow my simple steps to locate the cause of the issue.

**In my opinion:**

You might do some similar operation like mine. Maybe `Exclude from Project`, maybe delete the ItemGroup content in xx.csproj file, or what.

The result is deleting the ItemGroup for those .png files in xx.csproj. If you create a new Blank App(UWP), and check its content of .csproj file you would see:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Properties\Default.rd.xml" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But these content is missing in your .csproj file.

These four files which are used in your appmanifest are indeed in your asserts folder.

But without the content ref in .csproj file, the build process can't find them properly.`Square150x150Logo.png`,`Square44x44Logo.png`,`StoreLogo.png`,`SplashScreen.png`

**As a workaround:**

So you can edit your xx.csproj file, and add the ItemGroup into it.
But I'm not **certainly** sure it will work. Since after my checking your .csproj file. Maybe the .png files are not the only things you excluded or removed!!

I'm not sure how many changes you've made to the project, so if above not helps, just create a new project and copy your core code into the new project.

Comment: Step number 2 was the answer. thanks. just got frustrated and didn't work on this for  a while

Comment: Yes, step2 is what i think can cause this issue. Thanks for your feedback:)